# After migration to SQL Server 2017 and IIS10 is annoyingly slow

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, migration

We run complex, stateful, rich transactions in an ASP.NET MVC 5 web platform online.

Currently, we are in the process of migration from old environment Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 and IIS 8.5 (.NET 4.5.1) to Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2017 and IIS 10 (.NET 4.6).

Unfortunately, after migration, everything working 3x times slower which is painfully annoying to our customers.

Can anyone please HELP US? I would appreciate any help and support.

here is the new version after migration http://66.23.227.124/IdeaPhotoBrowser
Here is an old version  http://homez.design/IdeaPhotoBrowser

Comment: There could be many causes, given the changes to hardware, OS, SQL Server, IIS. Assuming the database schema is identical (especially indexes), one quick thing to try is to rule out plan regression with `USE YourDatabase;ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION=ON ; `.

Comment: Performance tuning is a huge topic, and locating the culprit is both application dependent and experience dependent. Try to hire an experienced consultant, or simply open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com. You shouldn't suppose a community site like Stack Overflow can handle such support requests.

Comment: I second the comment by @MitchWheat. If you haven't rebuilt all your statistics and indexes then you need to. My experience suggests this is very likely the culprit.

Comment: Mitch, I'm here now to solve the issue, which quite terrible experience. The MS selling ppl announced 60% performance increase out of the box. But in reality, I have 3-5 times degradation. So I'm very happy if anyone can solve this issue

Comment: Mitch, how can I rebuild all indexes in an efficient way.  I have about 9 separated databases with many tables inside. Is any fast way to achieve this or should I manually re-build index, one- by- one using SQL Management Studio - which is quite a slow way?

Comment: Mitch. Have you examined SQL Server's error log(s)? Have you changed database's compatibility level? Yes, I had changed to 140 all my databases.

Comment: Tom is any way to re-build stats ? I don't know how to do this .. Pls let me know if u know or show me some relevant docs

Answer (score 0):

Start by rebuilding your indexes. You can run this command in each database:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "dbcc dbreindex('?')"
```

Also, check the SQL Server error logs for any configuration (or other) problems.

Comment: Ii had done the index rebuilding. Should I re-build stats? is any procedure to achieve this.

Comment: stats that are associated with indexes get rebuilt when you rebuild indexes. You have to rebuild column stats separately. I think you need to provide more information. Identify the slowest query, and post it's query plan and your table schemas.

Answer (score -1):

You could be using a different version of the SQL Server Cardinality Estimator on the new instance

This is specifically for folks who have upgraded to SQL Server 2014 or higher.

Use this command to make it faster..

ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION = ON
GO